# FirefoxWebElement to string?

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to get some data from a table I've located using xpath. The code and output is as follows (below), i've gotten this code from bits and pieces from various sources. I would like to be able to print the value "16.06" as a string and not "[u'16.06']" I have tried using splicing for the "elems" variable but it seems to be a FirefoxWebElement. Hence is there anyway to convert it to a string to splice or is there any other way round this? Thanks!

Attached are pictures of the website and what I am trying to extract.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31vbd.png)
***Username and password has been changed***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "http://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html"


driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

username = driver.find_element_by_name('name')
username.send_keys('XXX')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('XXX)

form = driver.find_element_by_id('sic_login_submit')
form.submit()

timeout = 5
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"

url = "http://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/financials.html?counter=D05.SI"
driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]""")
print([elm.text for elm in elems])
```

Output:
 - Timed out waiting for page to load
 - [u'16.06']

Answer (score 1):

This is (probably) a simple fix of the following:

At the end of your elems variable you can add `.text` to grab the text of the element. So in your code simply do:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]""").text
```

and that should work fine.

The reason it doesn't return what you want normally is because you are simply trying to grab an element. You're not grabbing the text of it or anything so the type stays to what the web driver understands which is the FirefoxWebElement type

This is only a guess and maybe not even what you wanted but the idea around this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! however in following the above code i get the following error.

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d332000a1c3b> in <module>()
     34 driver.get(url)
     35 
---> 36 elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]""").text
     37 print([elm.text for elm in elems])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'